# How to use RouterLink in HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

`Angular 2.3.0`

I defined an Angular 2 module like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponentRoute }  from './components/+app/index';
import { AppComponent }  from './components/+app/app.component';
import { HomeComponentRoute } from './components/+home/index';
import { HomeComponent }  from './components/+home/home.component';
import { ContactComponentRoute } from './components/+contact/index';
import { ContactComponent }  from './components/+contact/contact.component';

let app_routes: Routes = new Array();
    app_routes.push(AppComponentRoute);
    app_routes.push(HomeComponentRoute);
    app_routes.push(ContactComponentRoute);

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(app_routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ContactComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:[
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

The Home `Component` looks like this:

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: `./app/components/+home/home.component.html`
})

export class HomeComponent  { name = 'Home'; }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem is that `routerLink` is not working in the seperate `.html` file.
However, when I define the template inline, I can use it like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: `
        <nav>
            <a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
```

How do I get this to work in the seperate `.html` template?

**UPDATE**:

I realized I forgot the error I'm getting:

> Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

Thanks!

Comment: use same notation ike in the inline template. Then it should work. ``<a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>``

Comment: I usually just set the **<router-outlet></router-outlet>** in the app component. not in their children. Is there any reason for setting it in the home component?

Comment: Just to be clear, I get the following error in the browser console: ``Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.``. I updated my question.

Comment: @Bernhard I tried that earlier, but then the ``a`` element is not converted to a link, so it's not clickable. It just displays the text inside an ``a`` without the ``href`` attribute.

Comment: @Nicky Angular 2 an <a /> element to load another component shouldn't have the href property

Answer (score 9):

You can try like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/', 'contact' ]" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>
```

You can change first value of array `[routerLink]="[ '..', 'contact' ]"` based on your routing nested hierarchy. And add `RouterModule` into `app.module.ts` using `imports`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    ...
    ]
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I use `gulp-htmlmin`, which in turn uses `html-minifier`, where the [default setting for camelCase attributes is set to false](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference). Hence the updated error message saying `routerlink` instead of `routerLink`. Very subtle issue so hope this helps to anyone!

Comment: This link may be useful but it useless until you provide the detailed answer.